# Java: Enumeration from Set<String>

Tags: java, collections, set, enumeration

I have a simple collections question. I have a [`Set<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) object. I want an [`Enumeration<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Enumeration.html) of the `String`s in that `Set`. I need an `Enumeration<String>` since I am overriding a method that specifically returns an `Enumeration<String>`. What is the cleanest/best way to go about it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

EDIT: There's no need to write your own (although I'll leave the implementation below for posterity) - see [Kevin Bourrillion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118469/840714) for the one in the JDK.

---

If you *really* need an enumeration, could could use:

```
Enumeration<String> x = new Vector(set).elements();
```

It would be better to use `Iterable<E>` if at all possible though...

A better alternative is to write a small wrapper class around `Iterator<E>`. That way you don't have to take a copy just to find an imlementation of `Enumeration<E>`:

```
import java.util.*;

class IteratorEnumeration<E> implements Enumeration<E>
{
    private final Iterator<E> iterator;
    
    public IteratorEnumeration(Iterator<E> iterator)
    {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }
    
    public E nextElement() {
        return iterator.next();
    }
    
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }
    
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); 
        Enumeration<String> x = new IteratorEnumeration<String>(set.iterator());
    }
}
```

Comment: I just down voted as well.  No need to write your own implementation when the JDK has a static util method that does it for you as pointed out by Kevin Bourrillion.

Comment: @Snekse: If the previous downvoter had said as much, that would have been helpful. I can't delete my answer now as it's the accepted one, but I can point out Kevin's...

Comment: Your answer wasn't bad, there was just a better one available after the fact.  There should be a SO badge for having an accepted answer with negative vote totals (currently sitting at negative one) 
:-)

Comment: @Snekse: I have no problem with being downvoted due to the fact that it's already in the JDK. I just object to a downvote without a comment...

Comment: @Charlotte: If you could unaccept this answer (and ideally accept Kevin's) it would allow me to delete this one. Kevin's is a much better answer than mine, but I can't delete mine while you've left it accepted.

Comment: It's a pity there's not an option to remove acceptance of an answer by the answer author, without resorting to deleting the answer, I see this a lot on SO.

Answer (score 209):

[`java.util.Collections.enumeration(set)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#enumeration%28java.util.Collection%29)

**Javadoc**

> Returns an enumeration over the specified collection. This provides
>   interoperability with legacy APIs that require an enumeration as
>   input.

Comment: Effective Java Item 47: Know and use the libraries

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean enumeration in the mathematical sense the cleanest way to do this is via a for-loop, applicable to any class that implements `Iterable`:

```
Set<String> strs = ...

for (String s : strs) {
 ...
}
```

If you really require an `Enumeration` you could implement an adapter class to wrap the `Iterator` returned by calling `iterator()`.  There is an adapter class in the Apache Collections library: [`IteratorEnumeration`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/IteratorEnumeration.html).

Or you could use Google's Guava library:

```
Set<String> mySet = ...
Enumeration<String> = Iterators.asEnumeration(mySet.iterator());
```