# Read out of multiple files with one BufferedReader?

Tags: java

So i´m able to read out of an existing file like this:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Something/test.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Now i´m able to use bfr.readLine() and read line by line.
If i wanted to read out of another file, do i have to create a new BufferedReader or is there any way to read out of multiple files with one BufferedReader?

Comment: "_If i wanted to read out of another file, do i have to create a new `BufferedReader`_" - no; but you would need a new `FileInputStream`. See [`SequenceInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html). Also, it will be somewhat tricky to ensure that all the of files are closed correctly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What is the tricky part? I can't see it.

Comment: @YassinHajaj how do you ensure that all the files are closed correctly, even when errors happen?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Wouldn't a try-with-ressources help doing this? These are all `Closeable` implementations. Or maybe I'm missing something. Just curious really...

Answer (score 3):

You could use `SequenceInputStream` to read files sequentially.

```
File file1 = new File("C:\\Something/test1.txt");
File file2 = new File("C:\\Something/test2.txt");
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
SequenceInputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(fis1, fis2);
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

### Closing streams correctly

To close these two streams (and reader), just use `try-with-resources`:

```
    try (
            FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
            SequenceInputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(fis1, fis2);
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
    ) {
        System.out.println(bfr.readLine());
        System.out.println(bfr.readLine());
    }
```

### Using more than two streams

If there are more than two streams, we'd have to use the constructor that accepts `Enumeration` of `InputStream`s. The tricky part here, as mentioned by @Boris the Spider, is closing all the streams correctly. We could create an `Autoclosable` that would contain all the `InputStream`s to close, but then, before we construct that container, but after some of the streams were already constructed, an exception could occur, so some streams would remain unclosed.

A clean way is to include all the streams explicitly in `try-with-resources` statement:

```
    try (
            FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
            FileInputStream fis3 = new FileInputStream(file3);
            ...
            SequenceInputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(new IteratorEnumeration<>(Arrays.asList(fis1, fis2, fis3, ...).iterator()));
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
    ) {
        // .. read from bfr
    }
```

`IteratorEnumeration` is the one suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086010/7637120

Another option is to manually track a list of input streams that were already opened successfully and close them if construction of next stream fails.

```
public class InputStreams implements AutoCloseable {
    private final List<InputStream> streams = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<InputStream> getStreams() {
        return streams;
    }

    public void add(InputStream is) {
        streams.add(is);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        IOException firstException = null;
        for (InputStream stream : streams) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (firstException == null) {
                    firstException = e;
                } else {
                    firstException.addSuppressed(e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (firstException != null) {
            throw firstException;
        }
    }
}

InputStreams streams = new InputStreams();
while (moreStreams()) {
    InputStream nextStream = null;
    try {
        nextStream = getNextStream();
        streams.add(nextStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // the following will close nextStream and all the earlier streams
        try (InputStreams streamsToClose = streams) {
            if (nextStream != null) {
                nextStream.close();
            }
        } finally {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

try (
    InputStreams streamsToClose = streams;
    SequenceInputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(new IteratorEnumeration<>(streams.getStreams().iterator()));
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
) {
    // work with bfr...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address closing the streams - which is probably the trickiest part.

Comment: Nice answer Roman ! :) Since [tag:java-9] you also have the possibility to make the try-with-ressources more easy to read. More info : https://dzone.com/articles/try-with-resources-enhancement-in-java-9

Comment: @YassinHajaj thank you for the link, I've learned something new today :)

Comment: Not sure about the DZone article - the assumption is wrong. One can declare as many resources as you want in the block and they will all be closed - as in your answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Indeed you can declare how many resources as needed. The article's example is not optimal